# Array of objects , group by parent's object

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, ecmascript-6

I've got an array of objects. I want to be able to group objects in parent's object , parent object is determined by `broker: true`. Is there a way to convert this:

```
const data = [
    { id: 1, broker: true },
    { id: 2, broker: false },
    { id: 3, broker: false },
    { id: 4, broker: true },
    { id: 5, broker: false },
    { id: 6, broker: true },
    { id: 7, broker: false },
    { id: 8, broker: false },
    { id: 9, broker: false },
  ];
```

Into something like this:

```
const data = [
    { id: 1, broker: true, chunks: [
      { id: 2, broker: false },
      { id: 3, broker: false },
    ]},
    { id: 4, broker: true, chunks: [
      { id: 5, broker: false },
    ]},
    { id: 6, broker: true, chunks: [
      { id: 7, broker: false },
      { id: 8, broker: false },
      { id: 9, broker: false },
    ]},
  ];
```

Comment: where is you specific problem?

Comment: @NinaScholz what do you mean?  I want to be able to group objects in parent's object. I cant achieve that kind of grouping.

Comment: have you tried anything?

Comment: @NinaScholz Of course , that's why asked , thanks for the right answer anyway.

Comment: _"Of course , that's why asked"_ - Then why didn't you post your code? Just copy&pasting the answer from somebody won't help you understand what you've done wrong.

Comment: Because , i was trying to achieve the result with `for` loop. I was going to post my code , but someone posted an answer already.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could check the propery for `broker` and push either a new object to the result set, or push the object to the previous object's chunks array.

```js
const
    data = [{ id: 1, broker: true }, { id: 2, broker: false }, { id: 3, broker: false }, { id: 4, broker: true }, { id: 5, broker: false }, { id: 6, broker: true }, { id: 7, broker: false }, { id: 8, broker: false }, { id: 9, broker: false }],
    grouped = data.reduce((r, o) => {
        if (o.broker) {
            r.push(Object.assign({}, o, { chunks: [] }));
        } else {
            r[r.length - 1].chunks.push(o);
        }
        return r;
    }, []);

console.log(grouped);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `reduce` to add to an accumulator every time it runs into a `true` value, and if it runs into a `false` value, add to the previous object via the property `chunks`

```
data.reduce((a, cv) => {
 let len = a.length - 1;
 return  (cv["broker"]) ? (a.push(cv), a) : (a[len] 
 ["chunks"] || (a[len]["chunks"] = []), a[len] 
 ["chunks"].push(cv), a);
}, []);
```

```js
const data = [
    { id: 1, broker: true },
    { id: 2, broker: false },
    { id: 3, broker: false },
    { id: 4, broker: true },
    { id: 5, broker: false },
    { id: 6, broker: true },
    { id: 7, broker: false },
    { id: 8, broker: false },
    { id: 9, broker: false },
  ];

let result = data.reduce((a, cv) => {
let len = a.length - 1;
return  (cv["broker"]) ? (a.push(cv), a) : (a[len]["chunks"] || (a[len]["chunks"] = []), a[len]["chunks"].push(cv), a);
}, []);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score -1):

You have to go through the array, create a new one and evaluate the condition you need, if it is met, put it in the new array

```js
Object.keys(data).forEach((value, index) => {

  // code

})
```

Comment: `Object.keys()` for an array? O.o

Comment: Object.keys(data).forEach(key => { console.log(data[key].property) })

Comment: Like the `Object` in `Object.keys` already suggests, is this method for objects and not for arrays.

Answer (score -1):

You are going through the keys of each object

```js
Object.keys(data).forEach(key => {
  console.log(data[index].property)
})
```

found

Comment: Why the same "answer" twice?

Comment: Remember that it is an array of objects therefore you can use foreach